# How to run nginx in runc?

Tags: containers

I decided to take on a journey of containerization and learn more how containers work under the hood to gain more confidence and become a more proficient programmer. I am trying to run a simple nginx container in `runc` but I am stuck. I looked at the official documentation but there is not much details, I also googled it but didn't find any details so feel I need more guidance.

I have created an OCI bundle and acquired the root file system off of `nginx` image.

```
mkdir containers/nginx/rootfs
cd containers/nginx
docker export $(docker create nginx:alpine) | tar -C rootfs -xvf -

runc spec
```

Running `sudo runc run mynginx` gives me the default `sh` process but when I run `nginx` inside the container it errors out

```
/ # nginx
2023/03/12 22:33:52 [emerg] 6#6: chown("/var/cache/nginx/client_temp", 101) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
nginx: [emerg] chown("/var/cache/nginx/client_temp", 101) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
```

Why? Am I not root?

```
/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
```

I am.
The listing, though, shows that only `/dev/`, `/proc` and `/sys` are owned by root, other folders are owned by user `1001`.

```
/ # ls -l
total 64
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           360 Mar 12 22:33 dev
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 11 10:04 docker-entrypoint.d
-rwxrwxr-x    1 1001     1001          1616 Feb 11 10:03 docker-entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x   21 1001     1001          4096 Mar 12 20:35 etc
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     1001             0 Mar 12 21:59 hello
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 home
drwxr-xr-x    7 1001     1001          4096 Feb 11 10:04 lib
drwxr-xr-x    5 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 media
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 mnt
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  306 root     root             0 Mar 12 22:33 proc
drwx------    2 1001     1001          4096 Mar 12 21:26 root
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 run
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root     root             0 Mar 12 22:33 sys
drwxrwxr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Feb 11 10:04 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    7 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 usr
drwxr-xr-x   12 1001     1001          4096 Feb 10 16:45 var
```

What is going on? Can you help me?

Comment: You have incorrect ownership for files and probably missing CAP_CHOWN capability

Comment: OK, I used the official `nginx:alpine` Docker image so does it mean that the image was built to run `nginx` as root but the ownership for files in the container is wrong?

Comment: You run `docker export` with `EUID=1001`  so all ownership of files got reset to UID=1001

Comment: @AlexD I ran `docker export` preceded by `sudo` and added the CAP_CHOWN capability but still have the same issue.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Very informative video for a start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAhzoz2zJj8